# How to use sympy to convert all standalone integers in an expression that aren't exponents to 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Is there a way to use sympy to find/replace all standalone integers (that aren't exponents) to 1.

For example, converting the following:

```
F(x) = (2/x^2) + (3/x^3) + 4
```

To:

```
F(x) = (1/x^2) + (1/x^3) + 1
```

I've searched extensively on stackoverflow for sympy expression.match/replace/find solutions, and have tried using a Wildcard symbol to find and replace all numbers in the expression but I keep running into the issue of matching and replacing the exponents (2 and 3 in this example) as well as they are also considered numbers.

Is there a simple (pythonic) way to achieve the above?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the code you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How deep do you want to go?

Comment: J_H, didn't want to lead anyone on in any direction (luckily as Pranav's solution didn't use any of the methods I tried). Pranav, as deep as the rabbit hole goes!
Thanks both! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setdefault` used with `replace` is a nice way to go. The single expression below has 3 steps:

1. mask off powers and record
2. change Rationals to 1 (to handle integers in numer or denom)
3. restore powers

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> from sympy import Dummy
>>> eq = (2/x**2) + (3/x**3) + 4 + 1/x/8
>>> reps = {}
>>> eq = eq.replace(lambda x: x.is_Pow, lambda x: reps.setdefault(x, Dummy())
          ).replace(lambda x: x.is_Rational, lambda x: 1
          ).xreplace({v:k for k,v in reps.items()})
1 + 1/x + 1/x**2 + 1/x**3
```

Comment: I like this, it solves the issue of replacing exponents by substituting out the entire power term, will give it a good test, but selected answer in the meantime - thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that will recurse into your expression. For any expression `expr`, `expr.args` will give you the components of that expression. `expr.is_constant()` will tell you if it's a constant. `expr.is_Pow` will tell you if it's an exponential expression, so you can choose not to drill down into these expressions.

```
import sympy

def get_constants(expr):
    c = set()
    for x in expr.args:
        if x.is_constant(): c |= {x}
        if not x.is_Pow:
            c |= get_constants(x)
            
    return c
```

Now, you can get all the constants in said expression, and replace each of these constants using `expr.replace()`.

```
def replace_constants(expr, repl):
    for const in get_constants(expr):
        expr = expr.replace(const, repl)

    return expr
```

With your example expression, we get:

```
x = sympy.symbols('x')
F = 2/x**2 + 3/x**3 + 4

G = replace_constants(F, 1)

print(F)    #   4 + 2/x**2 + 3/x**3
print(G)    #   1 + x**(-2) + x**(-3)
```

Comment: I just realised that this will replace the 2 in x^2 if the constant 2 also exists elsewhere. For example, (x^2 + 2)/x^2 will be converted to (x + 2)/x^2.

Is there a way to distinguish between the powers and the standalone constants during the replace_constants() step?

Comment: @Sighonide that's a good catch. I'm not super-familiar with sympy, so I'll need to do some research